# Is it possible if variable isset() then process the second function?

Tags: php

If I have a function like this:

```
public function access_1()
    {   
        $this->db->set('Name', $name);
        $this->db->set('Description', $desc);
        $this->db->insert('access_user');
        $id_access_1 = $this->db->insert_id();

        return (isset($id_access_1)) ? _________ : FALSE;
    }
```

In `return (isset($id_access_1))` then in the blank (**_____**) it will process the second function and set the `$id_access_1` in that function.

Like this:

```
public function access_2()
    {

        $this->db->set('Access_1_ID', ____________);
        $this->db->set('Dept', $dept);
        $this->db->set('Section', $section);
        $this->db->insert('access_dept');
        $id_access2 = $this->db->insert_id();

        return (isset($id_access2)) ? $id_access2 : FALSE;
    }
```

Below is the controller, the function `access_2()` is inside `for each()`, like this one:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $this->structure_management->insert_batch($data);
            $data = $this->input->post('data');
            $access_2Data = json_decode($data,TRUE);
            foreach ($access_2Data as $getAll)
             {
           $this->structure_management->access_2($getAll);
             }
else{
}
```

In the program I have right now, when I click SUBMIT button it will process the two functions but then I figure out how will I get the ID of function `access_1()` if it is in `AUTO_INCREMENT`. And you will notice in the seconde function `access_2()`, there's a blank (**__________**) in `$this->db->set('Access_1_ID', ____________);` because there I will input the `ID` in the first function `access_1()`. It will set only one row for the function `access_1()` and in function `access_2()` it will iterate because it is inside `for each()`.  But every iteration I will only get only one ID which has in `access_1()` when I set in database.

If you have questions, if you think my explanation seems not understandable, feel free to ask me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about what `isset` function does.  You already have

```
$id_access_1 = $this->db->insert_id();
```

As a result of this call, `$id_access_1` will *always* be set; instead you need to check what it is set to.  I don't know the details of your `$this->db` class, but for the sake of the argument, I'll assume that method `insert_id` returns the ID of the newly inserted row or `FALSE` on error (as is the norm in PHP).

Then what you need to do is check whether you got `FALSE` on the first call; if not, then invoke the second function and return its result, otherwise return FALSE.  In the second function you don't need to check anything at all, as simply returning the result of call to `insert_id` will either return `FALSE` if something went wrong or the actual ID - hence you can simply return that result.

You would end up with something like this:

```
public function access_1()
{   
    $this->db->set('Name', $name);
    $this->db->set('Description', $desc);
    $this->db->insert('access_user');
    $id_access_1 = $this->db->insert_id();

    return $id_access_1 !== FALSE ? access_2($id_access_1) : FALSE;
}


public function access_2($id)
{

    $this->db->set('Access_1_ID', $id);
    $this->db->set('Dept', $dept);
    $this->db->set('Section', $section);
    $this->db->insert('access_dept');
    $id_access_2 = $this->db->insert_id();

    return $id_access_2;
    //this will return either FALSE or the proper ID
    //based on the result of $this->db->insert_id() call
}
```

Comment: Is there anything I will change in the controller?

Comment: @user987654321 I don't know - that really depends on your logic and what you're trying to achieve.  I simply provided the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: It is not allowed to call the function in the condition.

Comment: @user987654321 Since when??  You can call a function and return its result _anywhere_ you can return a variable value.  The code above compiles (lints) perfectly fine.